How to change the parameter of a tf.keras.Sequential model directly from the variable it is stored in?
Context :
I am working on a text classification problem in tensorflow. To illustrate the nature of my problem consider the following model as an example.
Note : to understand my problem you only need to look at the first 3 layers.
encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization( standardize = "lower_and_strip_punctuation", 
                                            output_mode = "int",
                                            output_sequence_length = 300) 

# have the encoder learn the vocabulay from the training data set  
encoder.adapt(X_train) 

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string),
                             encoder,
                             tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = encoder.vocabulary_size(),
                                                       output_dim = 128
                                                           ),
                             tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 32,                             
                                                    kernel_size = 2,
                                                    activation = "relu"),                      
                             tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = "relu"),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = "softmax")
                            ]
                           )

As you can see, the way I build this model requires some training data in order for the TextVectorizer layer to learn the vocabulary, and to set the correct dimensions for my embedding layer.

At the current stage I am trying to fine tune the parameters of my model. To do this I am using keras-tuner and using hypermodels from that library.
I therefore have to implement the build and fit methods in the class below
class MyHyperModel(kt.HyperModel): # inherits the hyper model class
    
    def build(self, hp): # construct a model
        
        # return a model
        
    def fit(self, hp, model, X, y): # fit the model obtained in "build" method to the data X,y
    
        # returns validation f1_score 


Issue :
This brings us to the issue I have. My model so far has always been built with access to the training data. However I do not have access to that data when implementing the build method.
Currently the build method will return a model as follows
encoder = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization( standardize = "lower_and_strip_punctuation", 
                                            output_mode = "int",
                                            output_sequence_length = 300) 

# we do NOT adapt encoder to the training data because we do not have access here.
# encoder.adapt(X) 

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string),
                             encoder,
                             tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = encoder.vocabulary_size(),
                                                       output_dim = 128
                                                           ),
                             tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 32,                             
                                                    kernel_size = 2,
                                                    activation = "relu"),                      
                             tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = "relu"),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = "softmax")
                            ]
                           )

In order to fit the model and get the validation score I must therefore modify the model inside of the fit method where the model is stored in the model variable.
Note : technically I could just build a new model from scratch with the parameters I want inside of the fit method and use that one to compute the F1 score but this is not an elegant solution. I would rather modify the existing model.
I tried doing something like
model.get_layer(index = 0).adapt(X)


but this doesn't update the model.
How can I solve this issue?
